# Django - custom admin action

Tags: django, admin

I've got model

```
class Book(models.Model):
    ...
    accepted = models.BooleanField()
```

and admin

```
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('__unicode__', 'accepted')
    actions = ('change_accepted',)

    def change_accepted(self, request, queryset):
            queryset.update(accepted=True)
```

This create custom action from *scrollable action menu*. I've need something like this: http://www.theotherblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/django_admin.jpg (last column). I mean - action from list_display. Is it possible?

Sorry for my english.

Comment: What exactly do you want in that last column? A link to something, or an actual form button?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're rather looking for calling a method on the admin class through [`list_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) which should display a link in the current row than for an admin action:

```
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('__unicode__', 'accepted', 'my_linK')

    def my_link(self, obj):
        return "<a href="%s">View on site</a>" % obj.get_absolute_url()
```

Comment: I need change content of 'accepted' field - from False to True.

Comment: @sigo [list_editable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_editable) perhaps?

Comment: @rebus, I think this will link 'Accept', but your's solution is great too. Thanks.